# reactjs - how to make background full screen behind the register form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried a lot of the other answers on this particular topic. New to `reactjs`.
Load image:

```
import Background from '../images/background-small.jpg';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

export class Register extends Component {
    state = {
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password2: '',
    };

    static propTypes = {
        register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
    }

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { username, email, password, password2 } = this.state;
        if(password !== password2) {
            this.props.createMessage({ passwordNotMatch: "Passwords do not match" });
        } else{
            const newUser = {
                username,
                email,
                password
            }
            this.props.register(newUser);
        }
    };

    onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  render() {
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }

    const { username, email, password, password2 } = this.state;

    return (
        <div style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")", backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' }} >
        <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className = "card card-body mt-5">
            <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} value={username} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={email} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password2" 
                    onChange={this.onChange} value={password2} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { register, createMessage })(Register);
```

I have tried using `css` where I wrap the code in a `.container` and a lot of the answers I found. Somehow none of them make the background fullscreen. It would be great to understand the reason and how top control the background height width.

Edit:

If I am understanding this correctly: the height and width of the `register form` for lack of better word is making the background fit the dimensions of the form. How would I change this?

Edit 2:

Rendered `html`:

```
<div class="container">
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/5e3641728b3f65a7cc8b0971bcba015e.jpg&quot;); 
background-position: center center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
<div class="card card-body mt-5">
<h2 class="text-center">Register</h2><form>
<div class="form-group"><label>Username</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group"><label>Email</label><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value=""></div><div class="form-group"><label>Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value=""></div><div class="form-group"><label>Confirm Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" value=""></div><div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button></div><p>Already have an account? <a href="#/login">Login</a></p></form></div></div></div></div>
```

`css`:

```
    --bs-blue: #2780e3;
    --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
    --bs-purple: #613d7c;
    --bs-pink: #e83e8c;
    --bs-red: #ff0039;
    --bs-orange: #f0ad4e;
    --bs-yellow: #ff7518;
    --bs-green: #3fb618;
    --bs-teal: #20c997;
    --bs-cyan: #9954bb;
    --bs-black: #000;
    --bs-white: #fff;
    --bs-gray: #868e96;
    --bs-gray-dark: #373a3c;
    --bs-gray-100: #f8f9fa;
    --bs-gray-200: #e9ecef;
    --bs-gray-300: #dee2e6;
    --bs-gray-400: #ced4da;
    --bs-gray-500: #adb5bd;
    --bs-gray-600: #868e96;
    --bs-gray-700: #495057;
    --bs-gray-800: #373a3c;
    --bs-gray-900: #212529;
    --bs-primary: #2780e3;
    --bs-secondary: #373a3c;
    --bs-success: #3fb618;
    --bs-info: #9954bb;
    --bs-warning: #ff7518;
    --bs-danger: #ff0039;
    --bs-light: #f8f9fa;
    --bs-dark: #373a3c;
    --bs-primary-rgb: 39,128,227;
    --bs-secondary-rgb: 55,58,60;
    --bs-success-rgb: 63,182,24;
    --bs-info-rgb: 153,84,187;
    --bs-warning-rgb: 255,117,24;
    --bs-danger-rgb: 255,0,57;
    --bs-light-rgb: 248,249,250;
    --bs-dark-rgb: 55,58,60;
    --bs-white-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --bs-black-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --bs-body-color-rgb: 55,58,60;
    --bs-body-bg-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --bs-font-sans-serif: "Source Sans Pro",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    --bs-font-monospace: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    --bs-gradient: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    --bs-body-font-family: var(--bs-font-sans-serif);
    --bs-body-font-size: 1rem;
    --bs-body-font-weight: 400;
    --bs-body-line-height: 1.5;
    --bs-body-color: #373a3c;
    --bs-body-bg: #fff;
    --bs-border-width: 1px;
    --bs-border-style: solid;
    --bs-border-color: #dee2e6;
    --bs-border-color-translucent: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    --bs-border-radius: 0.375rem;
    --bs-border-radius-sm: 0.25rem;
    --bs-border-radius-lg: 0.5rem;
    --bs-border-radius-xl: 1rem;
    --bs-border-radius-2xl: 2rem;
    --bs-border-radius-pill: 50rem;
    --bs-link-color: #2780e3;
    --bs-link-hover-color: #1f66b6;
    --bs-code-color: #e83e8c;
    --bs-highlight-bg: #ffe3d1;
    color-scheme: light;
    font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
    font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
    font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
    line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
    color: var(--bs-body-color);
    text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1320px;
```

Comment: `background-size:cover;` ?

Comment: @stckvrw I get an error if I try `background-size: cover` currently it is: `backgroundSize: 'cover'`.

Comment: There is no an issue with your `style={{ ... }}`. Do you successfully import `Background` ?

Comment: @stckvrw yes, the background is showing. Please see my edit. I think the issue is it fits to the register form dimensions rather than full screen. I just tried removing all the code after the background image and now it is just a thin strip below the header.

Comment: Post just full rendered HTML and CSS

Comment: @stckvrw I tried to add it, I am not sure if that is what you meant.